# What is the equivalent mode of transport for RV, camper, Caravan in Routing api?

Tags: here-api

We are using routing api to get expected time and distance of a travel from point A to point B with specific mode of transport.

As routing api accepts only pre-defined set of modes of transport like car, car hov e.t.c. Where can we map transport modes like RV, Caravan, Camper?!

Answer (score 0):

You can map RV, Caravan, Camper all to a truck (which is the general term in Here Fleet Telematics API) as shown below.

```
 GET http://cre.cit.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json
    ?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}
    &app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
    &mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled
    &driver_cost=10
    &waypoint0=50.10992,8.69030
    &waypoint1=50.00658,8.29096
```

For specific instances say calculating tollcost etc, you can use Trailertype= CARAVAN parameter (check our documentation) to get accurate results on caravan type. Basically it depends on your usecase. But for general routing purpose using type truck is enough.Hope this helps!

Comment: In that cases what will be car hov mode of transport will be covering. Can you please explain. What comes under car hov.